# How to load custom module js file in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta, requirejs

I have created banner slider module for magento 2.
I have called JS file using following ways and its working fine.
In block class I created following function

```
public function getBaseJs($fileName){

        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
            ).'bannerslider/js/'.$fileName;
    }
```

and this function is called in `bannerslider.phtml` file as following manner.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getBaseJs('jquery-1.7.min.js') ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getBaseJs('jquery.flexslider.js') ?>"></script>
```

> But, according to jQuery dependency mechanism of `require.js` How I
>   can do it ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution for my query. I would like to share it in details as below.

[image]

**Step 1:** Add your module js file under `<Vendor>/<Module_Name>/view/<area>/web/js/`

e.g. `<Vendor>/<Module_Name>/view/<area>/web/js/flexslider.js`

**Step 2:** Create `requirejs-config.js` file under `<Vendor>/<Module_Name>/view/<area>/`

e.g. `<Vendor>/<Module_Name>/view/<frontend>/requirejs-config.js`

Add following code to `requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            bannerslider: 'VendorName_ModuleName/js/flexslider'
        }
    }
};
```

Note: you may set your object name as per your choice. In my case I have set as `bannerslider` and do not add the .js extension to file name in `VendorName_ModuleName/js/flexslider`

**Step 3:** Call the `function` of your module js in `.phtml` file as following manner.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery','bannerslider'],function($){
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('.flexslider-8').flexslider({
                animation: "fade",
                controlNav: "thumbnails",
                slideshowSpeed: 2000,
                minItems: 2,
                maxItems: 4
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Its working fine for me.

Trace : Use `Net` tab to see requested URL of js file loaded or not.

[image]

Comment: better to use 'domReady!' plugin instead of $(window).load(), for example
require(['jquery','bannerslider', 'domReady!],function($)  { ...code execute only after dom load})

Comment: Yes, it will very useful.

Comment: @KAndy it depends, if you want the script to execute last, isn't it better to use $(window) ? doesn't that makes the script to run not only when DOM is read, but when all scripts are executed ?

Comment: And that way is not working for me ... says static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/gift.js  404 (Not Found) I have cleared the cache and the pub/static... bot nope.. not working

Comment: scratch that, it is working... domReady! not working though... how can i tell a script to run after all other scripts have been loaded, or that is not existent in current magent2 methodology ?

Comment: Does the above method works if I include prototype instead of jquery ?

Comment: I have added js as you mentioned. But do I need to add following line to add js require(['jquery','subscriptions']});, If i don't don this js file is not loaded 
Could please guide

Comment: This actually saved me.. Been looking for this since I'm a beginner in Magento thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

My way is:

### Step 1

Include an extension's base javascript file using layout instructions.

### Step 2

Require the extension's other javascript files from the base file with RequireJS:

```
require(
    [
      'jquery', 
      '{VendorName}_{ModuleName}{path_to_js_file/relative_to/view/web/no_js_at_end}'
     // ex. Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/grid/sticky/sticky.js
     // became Magento_Ui/js/grid/sticky/stick
    ], 
    function($, someOtherLibrary) {
        // custom code here...
    );
});
```

Comment: got an error require is not defined, because my js is loaded before requirejs