# How do add css, js in customview.phtml in view magento2?

Tags: magento2, blocks, magento-2.0

I have custom view.phtml. I Want add my.css and my.js in `<head></head>`
2 file in **app\code\Test\New\view\frontend\web\css**.

How do it?

Comment: was bellow  answer useful ?

Answer (score 6):

You can add CSS file as following way for your custom module.

Open you layout file e.g. `modulename_index_view.xml` and following code in `<head>`

```
<head>        
        <css src="Test_New::css/my.css"/>
</head>
```

to **add custom module JS** file you can use standard way as mentioned with below link.

[How to load custom module js file in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85851/how-to-load-custom-module-js-file-in-magento-2)

**My suggestion (Optional)**

You can use the standard way of Magento 2 to call `css` and `js` rather than 
Call `CSS` and `JS` files directly into `layout` file.

You can call JS using `requirejs` module. (You can maintain dependency of code.)

You may call `css` file using `_module.less` just put it under `app\code\<Vendor>\<ModuleName>\view\frontend\web\css\source`. So It will call automatically as well as `_module.less` will compile by `grunt tool` and converted into your theme or module css