# How to implement js and css for phtml template file in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, css, backend

I have been struggling to find a correct way to implement css and js for my template file, which lies in M2's backend. I put a file named `default_head_blocks.xml` to implement fullCalendar's css:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/fullcalendar.css" />
        <css src="css/fullcalendar.print.css" media="print" />
    </head>
</page>
```

I don't really know if this is okay or not. Also, requirejs file mapping is quite tricky, at least for me, to implement. The offical devdocs on this is not very helpful. Is there a way to do these with least pain possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need edit your layout to:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <head>
    <css src="Namespace_YourModule::css/fullcalendar.css" />
    <css src="Namespace_YourModule::css/fullcalendar.print.css" media="print" />
  </head>
</page>
```

This location of `.css` file: `Namespace/YourModule/view/adminhtml/web/css/fullcalendar.css`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you show me how to implement a custom js file for template?

Comment: @Hau Pham, answer is mentioned at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86527/how-do-add-css-js-in-customview-phtml-in-view-magento2/86541#86541