# How to change the copyright background-color at footer in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, admin, frontend

I want to change the background-color of footer(copyright) without configuring the less file. Is it possible through the admin panel ?

Comment: U can not do it in admin panel. if want u can add custom file css to do it. so if u don't know how to add your file css pls going to this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86527/how-do-add-css-js-in-customview-phtml-in-view-magento2 or contact me.

Comment: Where can i contact you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it from admin.

> Admin > Content > Configuration > Select your store view > HTML Head

**Scripts and Style Sheets**

```
<style>
    .copyright {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
```

[image]

Then run command:

> php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: I don't have a module.

Comment: @PiepPiper I have update my answer and you will do it from admin

Comment: @PiepPiper have you tried it?

Comment: Super genius. Will it work on the welcome message also? The important is not really necessary.

Comment: @PiepPiper It will effect on all, you can do it

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Admin > Content > Configuration > Select your store view > HTML Head > Scripts and Style Sheets**

Then add the following :

```
<style>
    .copyright {
        background-color: yourcolor;
    }
</style>
```