# java script 404 error in custom module

Tags: magento2, json

I created one module and i want to add js file to that module but in DOM i am getting "404 not found" my file are
**My\Helloworld\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            test1: 'My_Helloworld/js/test1'
        }
    },
};
```

**My\Helloworld\view\frontend\web\js\test1.js**

```
define([
    "jquery"
], function($) {
    "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('Test JS');
    });
});
```

**My\Helloworld\view\frontend\templates\helloworld.phtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery','test1'],function($){
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('.flexslider-8').flexslider({
                animation: "fade",
                controlNav: "thumbnails",
                slideshowSpeed: 2000,
                minItems: 2,
                maxItems: 4
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `require(['jquery','test1'],function($){...` try it with this:

```
require(['jquery','My_Helloworld/js/test1'],function($){ ...
```

This way you won't need the `requirejs-config.js` file.

Comment: thanks marius this is helped me lot...but i am not understanding that what wrong with requirejs-config.js file

Comment: Me neither. If I find something I will post it here.

Comment: **requirejs-config.js::** in my case it is somehow missing "/js/" part in the url, which is why it's throwing 404. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can get it in any .phtml file by path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('Package_Module::css/flexslider.css')?>">
```

**I hope this will help you.**

Answer (score 0):

Please compare your try with [How to load custom module js file in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85851/how-to-load-custom-module-js-file-in-magento-2/85920#85920). still you get same error then please comment here. You can implement use `shim` to maintain `jQuery` dependency.

Comment: i followed this one only but unfortunately i was getting 404 error but marius answer solved this 404 not found error.