# Magento 2: How to load the js file in the xml file?

Tags: magento2, template, javascript

Magento Version: 2.0.0

There have some javascript files should be loaded into the template. How to load them such as importing the css file in  tag?

Answer (score 2):

```
<head>
    <css src="My_Module::css/style.css"/>
    <script src="My_Module::js/script.js" />
</head>
```

Here is the example. However, you need to take into account, that this `script.js` will be loaded synchronously, unlike all core scripts, like `jquery.js` (that are loaded via `requirejs`) so you can't use for example `$` in your `script.js`.
If you do want to use all core scripts features, register your script using `requirejs-config.js`. Good explanation is here [How to load custom module js file in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85851/how-to-load-custom-module-js-file-in-magento-2)

Comment: your code is working now. but i want to use require.js to load the custom js file. so, could you check my another question where is wrong in my configuration?
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107045/magento-2-whats-wrong-with-my-js-config
Thanks.

Comment: @mike this reference gives 404 for me

Comment: thanks. i have found the solution because i made a mistake on my code. So, i deleted my question.