# Magento2 add a custom javascript file to admin pages

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, javascript

How can we add a custom script to administration pages in Magento2?

[How to load custom module js file in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85851/how-to-load-custom-module-js-file-in-magento-2)
Seems to work well for the frontend pages.

Is it possible to do the same for admin pages?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is in no way a duplicate, why have some many users marked it as one?