# How to include custom JS files in magento 2 custom module

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, requirejs

I am well aware of a RequireJS feature of Magento 2. I used it quite well for some JS scripts.

```
require(['jquery', 'ajaxform', ''], function (jQuery)
{
         // JS code
});
```

But now I have a template HTML for which I have custom JS files to perform actions.

Like -

```
<div class="font-dp">
     <div class="">
          <select class="form-control" id="font-dropdown">
          </select>
       </div>
</div>
```

Now here I am fetching options for above select tag dynamically using JSON from a custom JS file.
I have not used any JS code on the template file. I have called events on each HTML element from custom JS files. I have nearly 15-20 JS files like this.

So I am confused about how to include these JS files in my custom module. I have rendered my template on front-end using the custom module. How should I add JS files?

Comment: Can you use app\code\Custom\Module\view\frontend\layout\XXXXXXX.xml <head></head>?

Comment: How would it work? It is not  `requireJS` way, is it?

Comment: Do you want to include your JS files in your Custom Module right? You need `requireJS` way ok got it

Comment: This will help you http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85851/how-to-load-custom-module-js-file-in-magento-2 & http://inchoo.net/magento-2/custom-javascript-in-magento-2-with-requirejs/

Answer (score 8):

I found a solution at last. Thanks @mike-smith for reference.

I added something like this in `Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/modulename_index_index.xml`

```
 <head>
    <!--For CSS-->
    <css src="Namespace_Modulename::css/my_custom.css"/>

    <!--and for JS-->
    <link src="Namespace_Modulename::js/my_custom.js"/>
</head>
```

I added CSS file `my_custom.css` in `Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/web/css/` folder and JS file `my_custom.js` in `Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/web/js/` folder.

Comment: Is this the recommended way?

Comment: Hello @HungryDB, I have added js file but in console it is showing "jQuery not defined", how to add custom js file after jquery load? please reply.

Comment: @Vinaya: try this snippet 
`require([ 'jquery'], function($){  $(document).ready(function($) {  //your code  }); });`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I add dotdotdot library in my magento2 custom theme.

**1. Download and add Js Library in your theme following the path:**

```
// app/design/frontend/Namespace/themename/web/js/jquery.dotdotdot.min.js
```

**2. Create a theme's requirejs file as follow and let the requirejs know newly added library.**

```
// app/design/frontend/Namespace/themename/requirejs-config.js
var config = {
   map: {
       '*': {
           dotdotdot: 'js/jquery.dotdotdot.min',
       }
   }
};
```

**3. Use the added library in your theme's main js file as follow:**

```
// app/design/frontend/Namespace/themename/web/js/main.js
require([ 'jquery' , 'dotdotdot' , 'domReady!'],function($){
    $(window).load(function() {
        //custom js code
        /* $(".product-item-name").each(function(){
            $(this).dotdotdot(); 
        }); */
    });
});
```

**4. and include your theme's js file in your site's head as follow:**

```
// app/design/frontend/Namespace/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="js/main.js"/> 
    </head>
</page>
```

You can add any external JS library and custom file on every page in magento2.

Comment: How come you have added the JS via XML? This should be done via `x-magento-init` or `mage-init`.

Comment: @BenCrook is it the wrong way to my custom add Js file via xml in head? If it is, please share with me the alternate and the best way to achieve this. For me it is working fine. Thanks

Ref: https://mage2.pro/t/topic/34

Comment: I would recommend giving http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html a read