# How to add JS library to Magento 2?

Tags: javascript, onepage-checkout, requirejs, 3rd-party-library

I need to add the jsPDF library to my Magento 2 Luma theme, so I can use it on the checkout success page.

Comment: please review this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/190318

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a module using that structure below.

**1 - Add you PHTML with the JS call via PHTML**

> app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="JSPDF" template="MyCompany_MyModule::js_pdf.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**2 - Create your PHTML in order to instantiate the JS Library**

> app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/view/frontend/templates/js_pdf.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[[
    require(['jquery', 'jspdf' ], function ($, jsPDF) { 
        const pdf = new jsPDF(); 
        $('.print_button_pdf').click(function (){ 
            pdf.text(10, 40, Order); pdf.save('order.pdf');
        });    
    });
    // ]]>
</script>
```

**3 - Call the script via RequireJS**

> app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'jsPDF' : ['//unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.min', 'MyCompany_MyModule/jspdf.min']
    },
    shim: {
        'jsPDF' : ['jquery']
    }
};
```

Comment: U have to call $, jsPdf in your script, and i download the library and add it to my module view/frontend/web/js

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" >// <![CDATA[
        require(['jquery',
 'jspdf'
],

 function ($, jsPDF,) {
    
            
  const pdf = new jsPDF();

$('.print_button_pdf').click(function (){  pdf.text(10, 40, `Order`);   pdf.save('order.pdf'); });
              
                    
        });
    
// ]]></script>

Comment: How come you've added JS to a PHTML file? Wouldn't JS be better in a JS file?

Comment: @BenCrook in my opinion, it would be better if there are a lot of DOM manipulations relative to this module, or if the dev. wants to abstract the DOM manipulations of the theme, it is not something that we can't find in the core though.
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/form.phtml

Comment: can you please send the download link in magento 2.3 extension link