# Magento 2: How to add custom grid?

Tags: magento2, javascript, adminhtml, backend

How can I add this code in Magneto2 admin page.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#MyTable').DataTable( {
    initComplete: function () {
        this.api().columns().every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );
            //to select and search from grid
                    column
                        .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );

            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    }
} );
} );
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="MyTable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Postion</th>
            <th>Technologies</th>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Experience</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>

        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Bikesh</td>
            <td>Srivastava</td>
            <td>Software Engg.</td>
            <td>Asp.net</td>
            <td>Hytech</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Navdeep</td>
            <td>Kumar</td>
            <td>Sr.Software Engg.</td>
            <td>Asp.net</td>
            <td>Hytech</td>
            <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sujata</td>
            <td>Sinha</td>
            <td>Software Engg.</td>
            <td>Asp.net</td>
            <td>Hytech</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Panakj</td>
            <td>Bhanadari</td>
            <td>Software Engg.</td>
            <td>Asp.net</td>
            <td>Hytech</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Harikant</td>
            <td>Kumar</td>
            <td>Web Designer</td>
            <td>Asp.net</td>
            <td>Hytech</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Payal</td>
            <td>Agrawal</td>
            <td>Software Engg.</td>
            <td>Salesforce</td>
            <td>Hytech</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Pritam</td>
            <td>Shekhawat</td>
            <td>Manager</td>
            <td>Salesforce</td>
            <td>Hytech</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Saurabh</td>
            <td>Kumar</td>
            <td>Software Engg.</td>
            <td>Asp.net</td>
            <td>HytechPro</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vinod</td>
            <td>Kumar</td>
            <td>Software Engg.</td>
            <td>Asp.net</td>
            <td>HytechPro</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <<td>Manik</td>
            <td>Bansal</td>
            <td>Software Engg.</td>
            <td>SharePoint</td>
            <td>HytechPro</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Brijesh</td>
            <td>Srivastava</td>
            <td>Asst.Manager</td>
            <td>Pharma</td>
            <td>Sun Pharama</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Krishu</td>
            <td>Srivastava</td>
            <td>Software Engg.</td>
            <td>Asp.net</td>
            <td>Hytech</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>            
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I need to show this grid on Magento2 admin page.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To archive,this you need to create a custom  Module where you will need do below:

- Create setup script which will create a  table.
- Create A model,resource model,Collection for this newsly create
  Table for read/write data
- Create admin section,where you will write the grid.

  Below blogs will be help you:
- https://webkul.com/blog/create-grid-edit-add-grid-row-and-installer-in-magento2/
- https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html
- https://www.aurigait.com/blog/magento-2-admin-grid/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need above custom grid, so how can I add DataTable Js Library.

Comment: why you need to add `DataTable Js Library`

Comment: For add new js library you can use  https://webkul.com/blog/include-use-custom-js-file-require-js-magento2/ or https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85851/how-to-load-custom-module-js-file-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

**Refer to this document for creating admin grid using custom module:**

*https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/create-admin-grid-magento-2.html*