# Add inline javascript to head - magento2

Tags: magento2, javascript, head, default.xml

I am struggling to load a script tag on my Magento website. I am trying to add this to the head by adding the below code. I have tried to add this to the `default.xml` and `default_head_blocks.xml`

```
    <!-- Bugherd -->
    <reference name="head.additional">
        <block type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="my_script">
            <action method="setText">
                <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">
                    <![CDATA[
                        <script type='text/javascript'>
                        (function (d, t) {
                          var bh = d.createElement(t), s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
                          bh.type = 'text/javascript';
                          bh.src = 'https://www.bugherd.com/sidebarv2.js?apikey=dkjfsd89id6sftsdghkjn3';
                          s.parentNode.insertBefore(bh, s);
                          })(document, 'script');
                        </script>
                    ]]>
                 </argument>
            </action>
         </block>
    </reference>
```

Error:

> 1 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'reference': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( attribute, block, referenceBlock, referenceContainer, container, move, uiComponent ).
>   Line: 637

Can anyone please advise how I can add my script to the head across all pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I would advise using Require JS to load this rather than adding it via XML like this, but if you're adamant you want to do it this way try this:

```
<!-- Bugherd -->
<referenceBlock name="head.additional">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="my_script">
        <action method="setText">
            <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">
                <![CDATA[
                    <script type='text/javascript'>
                    (function (d, t) {
                      var bh = d.createElement(t), s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
                      bh.type = 'text/javascript';
                      bh.src = 'https://www.bugherd.com/sidebarv2.js?apikey=dkjfsd89id6sftsdghkjn3';
                      s.parentNode.insertBefore(bh, s);
                      })(document, 'script');
                    </script>
                ]]>
             </argument>
        </action>
     </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Same as mtr.web's answer but uses class rather than block.

Comment: Still get the same error :/ How would I add the script with require JS? Do you think I could just add this script in its own file and add that to the head?

Comment: Thanks, this works when inside my default.xml, just gives same error when included within default_head_blocks.xml :)

Comment: That's because you can't use blocks inside `<head>` , there are very few things you can do inside `<head>`. It's the same thing vice versa to, you can't use head XML inside `<body>`. If that makes sense?

Comment: For it to work inside head you would need to use `<head><link src="Your_Module::js/filename.js"/></head>`.  To add it via Require JS this should help - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85851/how-to-load-custom-module-js-file-in-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 2, `referenceBlock` (basically) is a replacement for `reference`, so using that should solve your first error.  The second problem is that the `name` attribute for your block should be `class` instead:

```
<!-- Bugherd -->
<referenceBlock name="head.additional">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="my_script">
        <action method="setText">
            <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">
                <![CDATA[
                    <script type='text/javascript'>
                    (function (d, t) {
                      var bh = d.createElement(t), s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
                      bh.type = 'text/javascript';
                      bh.src = 'https://www.bugherd.com/sidebarv2.js?apikey=dkjfsd89id6sftsdghkjn3';
                      s.parentNode.insertBefore(bh, s);
                      })(document, 'script');
                    </script>
                ]]>
             </argument>
        </action>
     </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it still doesn't work :/ 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block', attribute 'type': The attribute 'type' is not allowed.

Comment: Removing the type stops showing the exception however it doesn't add my script to the head :(

Comment: It should be `class` instead of `type`.  Try my edited snippet

Comment: Thanks, this is working, just doesn't work in default_head_blocks.xml but works fine in default.xml

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your theme's default.xml:

```
<referenceContainer name="head.additional">
      <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_head" template="Magento_Theme::html/head.phtml" after="-"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

And create a `head.phtml` file which contains your inline JS in:

> /app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/html/

Clear static content and cache to see the changes.

You can add future inline JS to it when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add inline javascript in head from admin.

To add javascript please follow below steps:

- Open your site admin
- Go to Content > Configuration
- Edit your current theme
- Click on `HTML Head` tab
- Under that section, you will find the `Scripts and Style Sheets` label with textarea control.

Where you can add your Stylesheet or Javascript, which will be included before head closing tag in page HTML.